# Java Is okay to put input/output only in main method?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java Programing.
Lately I am doing the Java assignment.
I sew this method in user-defined class

```
public void intputRank( Scanner s) {
    salary = s.nextInt();
}
```

I was confused because I always want put I/O in `main` method (like in C++ I only write `cin` `cout` in main function). I have 2 reasons for doing this:

1. It's easy for me to see where my program accept `input`. When there is something wrong about I/O, I just need to debug the `main` method.
2. Scanner is a more complicated `Class`, use it as parameter would make unknown wrong.

So, kind Stack Overflowers, is it just a bad example or I understand something wrongly?

If it is the latter? Why not

```
public void inputRank( int asalary) {
    salary = asalary;
}

//in main method

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int asalary = reader.nextInt();

//then pass the asalary as parameter
```

Comment: Primarily opinion based but, passing the `Scanner` to the method does not sound like a good idea

Comment: I agree with you, keep your Input/Output away from your logic/computations. Of course, if that gets to be complex, breaking it down into multiple methods and helper classes is totally fine. Just make sure the same class only does I/O and not logic.

The real problem I have with that method (in addition to not providing any useful abstraction) is that it sets a stateful variable instead of just returning the value.

Comment: Might be better to wrap into it's own class ... but you're left asking the question why? `Scanner` does it pretty good job on it's own. I might consider doing something "like" this, but only if I wanted to, for example, limit the input the user can input - such as making a menu selection, but that's me

Answer (score 2):

If your program needs to be robust, e.g. when prompting for an integer it'll validate the input and re-prompt if bad, then having reusable helper methods is a good thing.

This means that you'll need multiple methods that use `Scanner`. Now, you can pass the `Scanner` object in as a parameter, or you can put it in a field, that's entirely up to you.

But the main point is that having code in a method that uses a `Scanner` is perfectly fine, and it really is a must for robust code, otherwise you'll ruin the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Example:

```
public static int promptNonNegativeInt(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    for (;;) {
        System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
        if (! sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("** Not a valid number, please try again");
            sc.nextLine(); // discard bad input
            continue;
        }
        int value = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); // discard any extra text on the line
        if (value < 0) {
            System.out.println("** Number cannot be negative, please try again");
            continue;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

*Example use*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int value = promptNonNegativeInt(sc, "Enter number");
    System.out.println("You entered: " + value);
}
```

Even more complex is if you need to prompt for an object with multiple fields. Isolating the code that does this is good programming (separation of concern), so writing a `promptMyObject(Scanner sc)` method is a good thing.

Especially if you need to prompt for various objects. If you leave all prompting code in the `main()` method, it'll be huge and unreadable. It would be a [God method](http://wiki.c2.com/?GodMethod), a variation of the [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object):

> A God object is an object that *knows too much* or *does too much*. The God object is an example of an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer to write methods that take simpler types over more complicated types. This makes them easier to compose and reuse later on.

In your example, the method that takes an `int` could be considered better than taking a `Scanner`, because `int` is simpler and more common than a `Scanner`. That being said, the name `inputRank` kind of implies it's doing to read / receive input, so I would be tempted to rename it to something like `applyRank` in this case.